# Why does extracting words using NLTK truncate the last 'S' on some ocassions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, nlp, nltk

I have written a python script to extract words from a pandas dataframe column. I observed that while extracting words, if the last letter of the word is 's', the last 's' gets truncated. Below is the actual code and output

**My code**

```
import re
import unicodedata
import nltk

# Create dataframe
data = ['gautam das',
        'vas',
        'kansas usa',
        'maryam lass']
  
# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name'])
df = pd.concat([df[col].astype(str).str.lower() for col in df.columns], axis=1)

def basic_clean(text):
    wnl = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
    text = (unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text)
        .encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        .decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        .lower())
    words = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', text).split()
    return([wnl.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in stopwords])

words = basic_clean(''.join(str(df['name'].tolist())))
words
```

**Output**

```
['gautam', 'da', 'va', 'kansa', 'usa', 'maryam', 'lass']
```

In this example, the words 'gautam','usa' and 'maryam' are extracted correctly but 'das' is extracted as 'da', 'vas' is extracted as 'va' and 'kansas' is extracted as 'kansa'. However 'lass' is extracted correctly its last 's' is not truncated.

**Question**: Why is this happening and how can I avoid it? I do not mind a solution that does not use NLTK as long as it extracts words efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using the `lemmatize()` method from the `WordNetLemmatizer()` class. Although the class is called a `lemmatizer`, it uses a special `_morphy` method that actually [stems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming#Examples) the words instead of [lemmatizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation) them. While I don't know what language model you're using, my guess is that the `WordNetLemmatizer` classifies the words with an 's' at the end as some sort of plural morpheme, which ultimately results in a cut-off.
For more information about the inner workings, see the documentation for the [WordNetLemmatizer](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/wordnet.html) as well as the [morphy method](https://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) of nltk.

If you do not need the token lemmatization, you can omit the process. Otherwise, you could consider using [spaCy](https://spacy.io/). You would need to download a language model of your choice and lemmatize your words using something like this:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
lemmas = []
doc = nlp(text)
for token in doc:
    if (token.is_stop == False) and (token.is_punct == False):
        lemmas.append(token.lemma_)
```

Hope this helps.